# How to display recently modified posts on recent post widget in wordpress

Tags: php

How to display recently modified posts on recent post widget in wordpress. right now recent post widget shows only newly posted posts. but i want to display recently modified posts. am using genesis framework.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. What did you try so far? Please post your current code example and explain where it failed. Thanks.

Comment: default wordpress recent post widget shows recently published posts. but i want to display recently published posts and modified posts.

Comment: What do you mean by *display recently published posts and modified posts*? Do you mean two recent posts widgets where the other one is ordered by post date and the other by modified date? Please edit the question and explain it in more detail, thanks.

Comment: recent posts ordered by modified

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to modify the ordering of the *Recent Posts* widgets through the [`widget_posts_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_posts_args/) filter that accepts `WP_Query` arguments.

One could order by the `post_modified` or the `post_modified_gmt` column.

It might also be possible to use the [`widget_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_title/) filter to target a specific instance or widget title.

Comment: can please give me exact code. recent posts ordered by modified

Comment: Please edit your question, with what you've tried so far and where it failed, Thanks @raja